# file_get_contents returns bizarre characters from raw text file

Tags: php

This is very bizarre. I have a .txt file on my Windows server. I'm using file_get_contents to retrieve it, but the first several characters show up as a diamond with a question make inside them. I've tried recreating the file from scratch and it's the same result. What's really bizarre is other files don't have this issue.

Also, if I put a * at the start of the file it seems to fix it, but if I try to open the file and do it with PHP it's still messed up.

The start of the file in question begins with: Trinity Cannon - that's a direct copy and paste from the text file. I've tried re-typing it and the first few characters are always that diamond with a question mark.

```
$myfile='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\fastpitchscores\\data\\2020.txt';

$fh = file_get_contents($myfile);

echo $fh;  // Trinity Cannon

echo $fh[0];  // �
```

Comment: Does the file look as expected in Notepad? It's possible that your txt file may have some rich text formatting in it.

Comment: Also check the encoding of the page <meta encoding="utf8">

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like whatever editor you used to originally create the file a [UTF Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning the file.

You typically can't edit the BOM from within an editor.  If your editor has a encoding conversion functionality, try converting to ASCII.  For example, in Notepad++ use Encoding->Encode in ANSI.